# SQL Server: Self-reference FK, trigger instead of ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, triggers, cascade

I need to perform an ON DELETE CASCADE on my table named CATEGORY, which has the following columls
CAT_ID (BIGINT)
NAME (VARCHAR)
PARENT_CAT_ID (BIGINT)

PARENT_CAT_ID is a FK on CAT_ID. Obviously, the lovely SQL Server does not let me use ON DELETE CASCADE claiming circular or multiple paths to deletion.

A solution that I see often proposed is triggers. I made the following trigger:

```
USE [ma]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TRG_DELETE_CHILD_CATEGORIES]    Script Date: 11/23/2009 16:47:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_DELETE_CHILD_CATEGORIES] ON [dbo].[CATEGORY] FOR DELETE AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
/* * CASCADE DELETES TO '[Tbl B]' */
DELETE CATEGORY FROM deleted, CATEGORY WHERE deleted.CAT_ID = CATEGORY.PARENT_CAT_ID
```

When I manually delete a category with child categories, I get the following exception:

[image: exception]

Any idea what is wrong with my trigger?

**UPDATE:**
Sorry for the edit, but I have another column CATEGORY.CAT_SCH_ID, which is a FK of another table CAT_SCH.ID. This FK has a CASCADE DELETE as well, meaning that once I delete a CAT_SCH, its CATEGORies must also be deleted. So, I get this error when I define the trigger:

*Cannot create INSTEAD OF DELETE or INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER 'TRG_DEL_CATEGORY_WITH_CHILDREN' on table 'CATEGORY'. This is  because the table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading DELETE or UPDATE.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The FOR DELETE trigger is raised *after* the original DELETE has been executed. To delete recursively, you need to write an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger.

The algorithm is like this:

- Insert the PKs from deleted into a temp table
- Find detail records of records in temp table
- Loop until no more records are found

DELETE records in the table by joining with temp table.

I described recursive deletion [in my blog](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/recursive-delete-in-sql-server/).

**Update**

I guess you just need to drop that ON DELETE CASCADE flag from your recursive foreign key in Categories. The CASCADE flag on the foreign key from CAT_SCH should not matter.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It seemed exactly what I need, but there is a little problem, could you take a look at the update? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but One cannot define `INSTEAD OF DELETE` on a table with the on delete cascade...