# Delete Records from a table recursively - SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

Table Structure

```
ID       DESC             PARENT_ID**

35151    Parent            35154
35152    System            35151
35153    Same as System    35151
35154    ParentsParent     35157
35156    Product           35157
35157    Login Group       35159
```

Where

Id is the primary key, and parent_id is the foreign key referenced in the same table

How can I delete records recursively, starting from the last child till the parent. If there is no child records the parent record should be deleted. I need to use transaction with rollback if something odd happens.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a recursive CTE to get the list to be deleted.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/9287/so3466713

```
-- SO3466713

CREATE TABLE #t (
    ID int NOT NULL
    ,[DESC] varchar(50) NOT NULL
    ,PARENT_ID int NULL
)

INSERT INTO #t VALUES
(35151, 'Parent', 35154)
,(35152, 'System', 35151)
,(35153, 'Same as System', 35151)
,(35154, 'ParentsParent', 35157)
,(35156, 'Product', 35157)
,(35157, 'Login Group', 35159)

;WITH tree AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM #t
    WHERE [DESC] = 'Parent'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.*
    FROM #t AS c
    INNER JOIN tree AS p
        ON c.PARENT_ID = p.ID
)
-- SELECT *
-- FROM tree
DELETE FROM #t WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tree)

SELECT * FROM #t​
```

Comment: Description is just a text. Please ignore it. The important thind is ID and ParentId.

Comment: @Sunil Ramu - [DESC] is just use to identify the tree you want to delete.  You can put any criteria you want to identify the root node from which you need to delete all the children.

Answer (score 1):

Look to this question:

[SQL Server: Self-reference FK, trigger instead of ON DELETE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783700/sql-server-self-reference-fk-trigger-instead-of-on-delete-cascade)

the FK with ON DELETE CASCADE does not works in SQL Express 2005, may be it will works in 2008

```
ALTER TABLE SomeChildTable 
CONSTRAINT YOurConstraintName 
FOREIGN KEY (YourParentId)
REFERENCES YourParentTable(ParentTableId) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I cannot use trigger as of now. Can I do it without trigger?

Comment: @Sunil Ramu, I have updated answer, however it could not works in MSSQL, but try please.