# How to emulate ON UPDATE CASCADE for SQL Server with triggers

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, foreign-keys, cycle, cascade

I have this SQL Server table which has a foreign key to itself that I use to store specific nodes in which tried to add the property `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for recursive updates that throws an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'X' on table 'Type' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Type] 
(
    [Id]     INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]   VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [Parent] VARCHAR(256) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Name] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([Parent]) 
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Type] ([Name]) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I know that there is [a valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783700/sql-server-self-reference-fk-trigger-instead-of-on-delete-cascade) posted in another question but it's for delete only and this is not what I'm looking for and since I'm not really that good in SQL don't know how to implement something like this for update myself.

How could I implement something like this with triggers?

Comment: An easy way to solve you problem is to use [ID] as an FK (as this will not change) instead of Name. This way you don't need to cascade update. The reason people have surrogate PKs e.g. `INT IDENTITY` is because they don't change. Big read: https://web.csulb.edu/colleges/coe/cecs/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=keys.php

Comment: The thing is that I need it to update. That's the whole reason why I'm requesting help on this one...

Comment: You are updating the name field, right? Change FK to point to ID column and you can update Name easily without breaking the relationship.

Comment: Good idea. I'll use that as a workaround.